# Most efficient way to check a range of dates using c# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am writing a booking system for a laptop refresh we are doing at our company. I need to be able to calculate which days have available slots and return them to be rendered on a calendar control (i.e. if a day has available days it is selectable, otherwise not.

The logic is as follows:

- A technician can build 3 laptops per day.
- On any day there may be 1, 2 or 3 technicians available.
- A table will hold the bookings already made

The total number of available slots per day is (in pseudo code):

```
((laptops per day) * (technicians available)) - slots already booked
```

My question is, what is the most efficient way to derive this? I guess it best done at the SQL side, with a function to return a table of dates with available slots. (It doesn't matter how many there are, so long as at least one slot is available.)

I can get my head round all of this so far. The bit I'm stuck on is that I don't want to have a table of all possible dates as it seems a bit inefficient. What I want to be able to do is effectively iterate over a range of dates between now and 3 months in the future and calculate the available dates from there.

I could do this in c#, but it strikes me as inefficient as it will have to keep hitting the SQL server for each possible day. Seems better to do it on the SQL side, but I don't know how to iterate over possible dates in this manner.

**SOLUTION SO FAR**

Using @Chris's method I can get a range of dates where the slots books don't exceed a set maximum:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE
DECLARE @endDate DATE

SET @startDate = GETDATE()
SET @endDate = DATEADD(m,3,@startDate)
;
WITH dates(Date) AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date])
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < @enddate
)

SELECT Date
FROM dates 
EXCEPT
SELECT date
        FROM tl_sb_booking
        GROUP BY date
        HAVING COUNT(date) < 3
```

This is just setting an arbitrary maximum of 3 bookings. Next step is to add the technician availability!

Comment: for date ranges are you looking at `actual dates or TimeSpan`

Comment: Actual dates I guess. Say I had a range from 1 July to 1 October, I'd want to iterate over each date (starting with 1 July) and check if there are available slots. If so, add it to the table to be returned - if not, don't. The end result I want is basically just a table with a single (date) column of dates where there are still available slots.

Comment: Do you really think efficiency will be important? Maybe you should consider more what type of code you find easier to write and maintain?

Comment: The reason I'm keen for the efficiency is that the web server is making the query over the internet. (Long story cut short it's so staff can access the page without a VPN. It gets the data back via a webservice hosted internally so I want to keep the number of calls to the SQL server to a minimum.)

Comment: Actually, @JeppeStigNielsen - as I write that it's just occurred to me the data processing will be done on servers in the same LAN as the internal server supplying the web service is local to the SQL server. Then the remote server is only bringing back the result of the web service anyway. Maybe you have a point...

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: If you are talking about 90 SQL queries (one for each day is his stated expectation for doing it in C#) for each hit then I'd say that probably will be inefficient. If there is no more efficient solution then you'd live with it but surely the whole point of this site is to find better ways of doing things (well, ok, sometimes its finding ways to do things at all).

Comment: query at once for the next three month then do the logic in c#?

Comment: Will your technicians work 365 days a year, without fail? Then you DO need a `BusinessDates` table to distinguish working days from non-working days. Your rules about 3 technicians may also change at some point in the future. Are you sure you want to hard-code your system to the magic number **THREE**? Wouldn't it make more sense to encode this information in tables? You can make the SQL call very efficient, pulling an entire range of date information all at once. I think you are worrying about the web->SQL performance too much, without true justification for doing so.

Comment: @ErikE - I oversimplified for the example. I actually have a table called technicianAvailability which has columns for techinician, availability (which is actually a list of office locations, plus "unavailable", and start and end dates - effectively it's just a load of date ranges saying where the technician is (or if not available) so it will be calculated by this.

Comment: Recursive CTEs will give you the best result, but without showing here all the moving parts, you will have to write the CTE yourself. What's nice about the CTE approach is that it encapsulates the iteration, while keeping business logic to the minimum - for better code/system maintainability, keep all your business rule processing in code.

Comment: @G.Stoynev Actually, Recursive CTEs are notoriously inefficient.  The best results come from Cross Joining constant lists.

Comment: @Ben I wish you would show us all the complexity, because as you can see just happened, we wasted time advising you about a better way to design the system due to not having the complete picture. We can help you with that part, too! Would you provide us with some script to create and populate relevant tables with sample data, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer addresses the part of the question that says: "What I want to be able to do is effectively iterate over a range of dates between now and 3 months in the future and calculate the available dates from there."

If you are using MSSQL then CTEs may help. To dynammically generate your date range code like the following can be used:

```sql
DECLARE @startDate DATE
DECLARE @endDate DATE

SET @startDate = GETDATE()
SET @endDate = DATEADD(m,3,@startDate)
;
WITH dates(Date) AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date])
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < @enddate
)

SELECT Date
FROM dates
```

That last SELECT can then join onto your other tables to get the dat for that date, do calculations, etc.

However, this isn't necessarily the best way to do this. Assuming you have some way to get a list of how many engineers are free on each day then there is no need to iterate over any other dates (since you know there will be no availability on those dates). So to this end something like:

```sql
SELECT count(1), Date
From EngineerWorkDays
GROUP BY Date
Where Date>= Getdate()
and Date < DATEADD(m,3,Getdate())
```

Would return a list of the dates where there is a possibility of work being done. Another select to get the work already allocated would then give you all the data you need. In your display code in c# you could then iterate over each day and check your datasets for any relevant data (whether engineers are available, how many, how much work already booked, etc.).

And don't forget if this is a shared app to check that there is still space on a date before booking something in in case somebody else booked something in after your did your initial query.

Comment: Cheers @Chris - any idea how I can approach the next bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212299/most-efficient-way-to-check-a-range-of-dates-using-c-sharp-and-sql-part-2

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
Select [DatesAvailable] From TableName
Where [DatesAvailable] Between BeginningDate And DateAdd(m, 3, BeginningDate) And
      SlotsAvailable > 0
```

This should give you any dates that have a slot available for the next 3 months...

Comment: What is the `datesavailable` table in this case? The problem Ben is having is that he doesn't want to have to have a table with all possible dates in I believe...

Comment: DatesAvailable is a field in a Ben's table.. "I guess it best done at the SQL side, with a function to return a table of dates with available slots. (It doesn't matter how many there are, so long as at least one slot is available.)"

Comment: Yes, so his question was about how to get that table of dates with available slots, not how to filter that table. And apologies for lack of clarity in first comment, I meant what is `TableName`.

Comment: That's right. I don't want a table with all dates. I want to have a table of "bookings" (i.e. slots already taken) and then check each date for the number of technicians (and therefore total possible slots available) and then subtract the number of slots already taken for that day. (Then move on in the loop to the next date and do the same check again.)

Comment: Select [AllDates] From Bookings
Where [DatesScheduled] Between BeginningDate And DateAdd(m, 3, BeginningDate) And
      (((laptops per day) * (technicians available)) - slots already booked) > MaxSlots     Just supply your formula for MaxSlots and you should get what your looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I've realised that I was confused by the original posters comment on getting all the dates available. If he has a list of availability of engineers by date then by definition he doesn't need any dates outside of that range.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @iToday As INT; SET @iToday = CAST(GetDate() As INT);
DECLARE @iDays As INT;  SET @iDays = 90;

WITH cte_0to9 As
(
    Select 0 As Num UNION ALL Select 1 UNION ALL Select 2 UNION ALL Select 3
    UNION ALL Select 4 UNION ALL Select 5 UNION ALL Select 6 UNION ALL Select 7
    UNION ALL Select 8  UNION ALL Select 9
)
, cte_0to99 As
(
    SELECT  (Tens.Num * 10) + Ones.Num As Num
    FROM        cte_0to9 As Ones
    CROSS JOIN  cte_0to9 As Tens
)
, cteDays As 
(
    SELECT  CAST(@iToday + Num As DATETIME) As PossibleDate
    FROM    cte_0to99
    WHERE   Num <= @iDays
)
, cteTechnicianUtilization As
(
    SELECT  t.Technician,
            d.PossibleDate,
            (Select COUNT(*) From Bookings b
             Where b.Technician = t.Technician
               And b.BookDate = d.PossibleDate) As SlotsUsed
    FROM    Technicians As t
    CROSS JOIN cteDays d
)
SELECT  PossibleDate, SUM(Util-3) As TotalAvailableSlots
FROM    cteTechnicianUtilization
WHERE   Util < 3
GROUP BY PossibleDate
HAVING  SUM(Util-3) > 0
```

Note that this approach, while longer (code-wise) is much more efficient than using recursion.

Comment: How much more efficient? The method I used with recursion ran quick enough in management studio that I can't imagine you'd notice any tangible benefit when selecting three months worth of concurrent dates. Do you have any benchmarks on the efficiency? I ask mainly because that code strikes me as being quite unreadable comparatively so the efficiency issue would have to be pretty significant for me to want to do it that way (and I should note I believe it could be, I'd just like to know how much).

Comment: @Chris Here's an article that measures it in great detail: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: Thanks. Reading now... Or not since I'm not a fan of "register just to read our pages" so I'm not going to. I'm sure they won't lose any sleep but I'm making a stand anyway, dammit. ;-)